# What to do if answer doesn't answer the question, but helps visitors with a similar problem

Tags: discussion, support, specific-answer

A while ago, I've posted an answer which doesn't really answer the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17597365/666835).

I've read the question once, and since reading the question my brain has transformed it into a problem which is not the correct answer to the question.

The answer has 20 upvotes and is clearly helping some visitors fix their issue (hence the upvotes).

Since the answer does not belong to the question, I would like to ask for some advice on what would be the best action.

Answer (score 4):

If there is an answer that has useful content, but is answering a different question than the question it was posed in response to, then simply *go ask a new question that asks what your post answers*, and post your answer to *that* question.

After doing that the content will still exist to be found by those that need it, users looking to solve the problem described in the original question will find solutions that actually solve their problem, and those looking to solve the problem you've answered will have questions asking what their actual problem is to find (rather than seeing a different question and leaving without checking to see if there is an answer that answers a completely different question).

Now, having said all of that about the general case, with respect to *your specific case*, I'm not so sure that that's warranted.  The problem of, "How do I parse a JSON string into a javascript object?" isn't exactly something that I think doesn't exist anywhere in the world, or even something that doesn't exist anywhere on SO ([as a quick search would indicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)).  I don't really think that such a question needs to be asked and answered.